# warning: libssl.so.1.0.2, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1

Tags: c++, libcurl, openssl, makefile, library

Estou tentando copilar um programa que precisa de algumas bibliotecas

```
LIBS = -g -lmysqlcppconn -lpthread  -lcurl -lboost_serialization -lreadline -lz -luWS -lssl
```

O problema é que `-lcurl` e alguns programas precisam de `libssl.so.1.0.2` e `-lssl` precisa de  `libssl.so.1.1`.
E quando tento copilar:

```
$make
g++ main.cpp sha1_sha1.o tools.o web.o api.o api-server.o paypal.o paypal_web_hook.o -o api.run -g -lmysqlcppconn -lpthread -lssl -lcurl -lboost_serialization -lreadline -lz -luWS  -I /usr/include/ -g
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.0.2, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
```

Tenho que deixar as duas bibliotecas instaladas, o que estou procurando é uma maneira de usar somente a mais recente para copilar o codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema instalando o `curl` atualizado fora do repositório. Pelo que percebi o `libssl` está mais atualizado do que o `curl` no Debian 9 e isso causa o conflito de biblioteca